# Hot to change Fireworks' transparent canvas color

Tags: background, fireworks

I want to reduce contrast of Fireworks' transparent canvas color.  [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWj1t.gif)
In Photoshop it can be setted up in General Preferences, but i can't find it in FW.
Maybe it's system color, whitch can be configured by registry?

Win 7, FW CS5

Answer (score 1):

I tried Required folder in the Fireworks program folder and realized there was a blank.psd file. I changed its opacity, turned off and launched Fireworks again but no luck.

I thought that psd file was creating some sort of base color for the transparency pattern but obviously it's not meant to be used in this process. At least, the way I tried it.

I think your best chance is to prepare a pattern and used to fill a rectangle area as big as your canvas and keept it locked at the bottom layer.